# Null connection from web app. to MySQL database on production server

Tags: java, mysql

I have a web application (java and MySQL) that works fine on my dev setup, but fails to connect to the database on the production server.

The context.xml file is:

```
<!-- MySQL -->
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="0"
    driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxxxxxxx?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    connectionName="yyyyyyy" connectionPassword="zzzzzzz" userTable="users"
    userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userRoleTable="user_roles"
    roleNameCol="role_name" />


<!-- Database Pool -->
<Resource name="jdbc/DB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
maxActive="25" maxIdle="5" maxWait="30000" removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxxxxxx?autoReconnect=true&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
username="yyyyyyy" password="zzzzzzz" />
```

The .java code that gets a connection is:

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/DB");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

There is data in the database, the user and password exist and are what they say they are in the context file, but the connection (from the java code) comes back as null. I have tried to look at the log files, but the ones I've seen don't contain anything generated by this application.

Note that I am not the admin of the production server, so I have to ask the sysadmin for any files or data. He is a helpful person, but simply saying "look at the logs" (for example) isn't going to do as much good as something more specific.

Thanks for any help,
Miriam

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there should be error outputs.

conn variable was initially set to be null and your catch block caught the error. looking at log file wont help because you output to console instead of output to a log file

e.printStackTrace();

set up log4j and use log with log.error(e);
or look for the error in console and post here

Comment: OK, I've gotten a better error message - what is says is "Could not load resource factory class". Our sysadmin suggested I try org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory instead of org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory. I tried it, and got the very same error message. Anyone here have any ideas?